# Nested acronyms

Tags: glossaries

I have acronyms that share a common term:

- CSMA -> Carrier Sense Multiple Access
- CSMA/CA -> Carrier Sense Multiple Access with Collision Avoidance
- CSMA/CD -> Carrier Sense Multiple Access with Collision Detection

Sometimes I need to introduce the term CSMA before referring to CSMA/CA, but sometimes I just refer to CSMA/CA, without introducing CSMA before. However, acronym explanations should be displayed in a somewhat readable manner, no matter which one occurs first in the document.

So, using the csmaca acronym alone

```
\gls{csmaca}
```

should produce, e.g.

**Carrier Sense Multiple Access with Collision Avoidance (CSMA/CA)**

and otherwise

```
\gls{csma} ... blahblah ... \gls{csmaca}
```

**CSMA with Collision Avoidance (CSMA/CA)**

Is there a good way to do this an a glossary? Maybe something nested like

```
\newacronym{csma}{CSMA}{Carrier Sense Multiple Access}
\newacronym{csmaca}{CSMA/CA}{\gls{csma} with Collision Avoidance}
\newacronym{csmacd}{CSMA/CD}{\gls{csma} with Collision Detection}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newcommand*\myglsentry[1]{%
  \protect\ifglsused{#1}{%
    \glsentryshort{#1}%
  }{%
    \glsentrylong{#1}%
  }%
}

\newacronym{csma}{CSMA}{Carrier Sense Multiple Access}
\newacronym{csmaca}{CSMA/CA}{\myglsentry{csma} with Collision Avoidance}
\newacronym{csmacd}{CSMA/CD}{\myglsentry{csma} with Collision Detection}

\begin{document}

\gls{csmaca}

\gls{csmacd}

\vskip 1ex\hrule\vskip 1ex

\glsreset{csmaca}
\glsreset{csmacd}

\gls{csma}

\gls{csmaca}

\gls{csmacd}

\gls{csmaca}

\gls{csmacd}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

The `\protect` makes sure the test is not expanded during the `\newacronym` definition.

Comment: This is brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for :)